# Typescript + Emotion Styled AS prop don't Infer the Component's Type

Tags: typescript, styled-components, emotion

I have a simple Button component

```
const Button = styled("button")
```

When I use it, I'm able to pass the `AS` prop like this :

```
<Button as="a">Hello</Button>
```

But when I try to get the `href` props, it's not working. Types from `Anchor` element don't infer and Typescript throws an error and says that `href` attribute doesn't exist on this component.

```
<Button as="a" href="https://example.com">Hello</Button>
```